# how to access grails application on Tomcat

Tags: grails, tomcat7

I'm trying to deploy a simple grails application on my test-server which is tomcat. I've built the WAR with `grails war` command so I've got a war file named: `simplgrailsapp-0.1.war`

When I deploy this to tomcat I'm getting a lot of errors which I'm going to resolve one-by-one. But the URL for the app from tomcat manager (`mytestserver:8080/manager`) is `http://mytestserver:8080/simplegrailsapp-0.1/` which doesn't seem correct. Because when I run the app locally the url is: `localhost:8080/simplegrailsapp`

I've also tried to access the app by `http://mytestserver:8080/simplegrailsapp` but that doesn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when you deploy a WAR to tomcat it will fall under the context of the name of the WAR file.  So in your case, the context becomes simplegrailsapp-0.1.  You can:

- rename your war file to whatever you want the context to be before you deploy it
- define a [Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) for the application in Tomcat

If you go with defining a context this can be added to the WAR file by creating a META-INF folder in the web-app folder of your project and creating the context.xml file there.

Comment: You can also specify the name of the war file when you build it with grails, e.g.: `grails war target/simplegrailsapp.war`.